# Пользователь вводит дату в формате "2015-12-30".Нужно "разбить" дату так что бы можно было с месяцем и днем делать условия

Tags: javascript

Например: с 12-ого месяца 22-ого числа по 1-й месяц 19-ого числа вывести пользователю знак зодиака-Козерог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете объект `Date` с вашей датой, и оттуда можно вытащить все данные - день, месяц, год.. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```js
var a = new Date("2015-12-30");
console.log(a.getDate());
console.log(a.getMonth()+1);
```

И работая с `Date` надо помнить, что `getMonth` возвращает номер месяца начиная с нуля. А значит чтобы получить актуальный месяц надо прибавить 1 (как в моем примере). Так же `getYear` возвращает число от 0 (начиная с 1900 года), но для этого у объекта `Date` есть метод `getFullYear()` который вам вернет конкретные 4 цифры года.
Список всех методов доступных объекту можно посмотреть по ссылке на MDN, что выше привел.

Comment: А что это у вас декабрь + 1 = 12? :)

Comment: Ммм, для этого ссылку на документацию скинул, сейчас распишу тогда..эх)